# Showing that $\{0\}\subseteq\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Suppose that $T:D(T)\subseteq X\to Y$ is a potentially unbounded linear operator, and recall that the multivalued part of $T$ is defined as the set $\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}$.

If $T$ is a '*genuine*' linear operator, or well-defined as a linear operator, one trys to show that $\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}=\{0\}$ only. That is, that the multivalued part of $T$ is just zero. The task here is to show the equality of these two sets, that is, to show (i) $\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}\subseteq\{0\}$ and (ii) $\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}\supseteq\{0\}$.

I believe that (i) is shown by working with the image of $0$ under $T$; that is, we take the operator $T$ as given, and show that $T(0)$ coincides with $0$. This is really the 'hard' part, usually. As for showing the other 'easy' direction, I was wondering if it would be sufficient to use the fact that $\ker(T):=\{x\in D(T):Tx=0\}$ is always nonempty from the linearity of $T$? Because then, one has that $0\in\ker(T)\implies T(0)=0\implies0\in\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}$, that is, $\{0\}\subseteq\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}$.

Is this sufficient for the other direction?

Comment: The set $\{y\in Y:T(0)=y\}$ is necessarily a singleton (otherwise $T$ would not even be a function). So you just have to show one of the containments (i) or (ii), and really both amount to saying $T(0)=0$. Note that if $T$ is nonlinear then we need not have equality, but when $T$ is linear it is very easy to prove: we have $T(0)=T(0\cdot 0)=0\cdot T(0)=0$.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but is it not true that you can have *multivalued* linear operators (linear relations) where we have that $y$ in the multivalued part not necessarily zero?

Comment: I've never experienced this. How do you define multivalued linear operators, and what would the kernel be (i.e. how do you say $T(x)=0$ when $T(x)$ can take many values)?